# Apache2 virtual host: www agnostic (*.hostname.com)

Tags: apache-2.2

I'd like to setup my virtual host to not require WWW. I want it to be subdomain agnostic. How can this be accomplished? Thanks!

Edit: sorry I was not clear. I host multiple sites on the same apache install, each with its own virtual host. I want each one to be accessible with and without www, ie: www-agnostic.

so www.google.com and google.com are both caught by the same vhost.

Thanks!

Comment: you probably don't need virtual hosts for this if you don't have subdomains. Just set the Listen 80/Listen 443 at the top of the httpd.conf.

Comment: Yeah, if you only want your website not to require www. then just don't type it.

Comment: Did you get this working? I saw you wrote a comment about how it didn't work, but looks like you edited or deleted it afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick assuming your DNS records are set straight:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: It's the same answer, but I'll edit it. Simply add virtualhosts as needed.